# Can realloc() expand into (and overwrite) subsequent data?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I'm in the process of learning C/C++ right now, and am confused about the behavior of the memory allocation functions, in particular `realloc()`.

Let's say I allocate ten `int`s:

```
int * i = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

I use that array for a while, but then realize that I need more space, so I reallocate `i` to 20 `int`s:

```
int * j = realloc(i, sizeof(int) * 20);
i = j;
```

However, it seems that the heap before reallocation could contain some other data *immediately after* the memory space initially allocated to i, since between allocating and reallocating `i` I could have performed another `malloc`, which could happen to allocate the space after `i`.

Then, when I reallocate, it would seem that the new space added to `i` would expand into (and overwrite) the data immediately after.

Is this what would happen?  If so, what should I do to avoid accidentally overwriting data?

Comment: If there is insufficient free space to fix up an inrease directly, realloc will move the existing data to somewhere where there is enough space.  That's why it returns a pointer.

Comment: ..or, of course, fail.

Comment: **Always** check the result of `malloc` & friends! (And of functions which can encounter a program-relevant error in general)

Comment: `Can realloc() expand into (and overwrite) subsequent data?` - no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to worry about `realloc` overwriting anything.  You also don't need to use an intermediate value to hold the new pointer, unless you want to attempt to recover from a `realloc` failure.  If not, then the normal way to do it would be:

```
ptr = realloc(ptr, new_size);
```

It will do one of three things:

1. If there is enough unallocated space to extend the old pointer, then it may do so, in which case it will return the original pointer.
2. Otherwise it will try to allocate new space, copy the old data, and free the old storage.
3. If it is unable to allocate new space, it may return `NULL`, just as `malloc` will.  So you should always check the return value before trying to use it.  In the case of a `NULL` return, the simplest action is to print an error message and exit.  If you want to recover and keep on running, then you will need to save the old pointer value so you can free it and avoid a memory leak,

Note that `realloc` may also be used to shrink the storage as well as grow it.  In other words, you can give it a smaller size than what was previously allocated.

Comment: There is a third possibility: the realloc may try to allocate new space, fail, and return NULL. In that case, if you did not save the old value of the pointer, you have a memory leak. That's why using a temporary pointer is always recommended (as is checking the return value). Of course, if you are content to let your application crash and burn on allocation failure, you could ignore that practice. But the fact should at least be mentioned.

Comment: @rici What is the recommended practice for handling those NULL allocations?

Comment: @rici I added a comment about the possibility of a `NULL` return value.  I guess I take it for granted that people will check for it.  If `realloc` fails, I normally just print an error message and exit, in which case I don't really care about the old pointer value.  But sure, if you want to do elaborate error recovery, you can save it.

Comment: @ostrichofevil If you can get away with just printing an error message and exiting upon a `NULL` return, then that's by far the easiest thing to do.

Comment: @ostrichofevil: that depends on your application. For non-critical, non-server, non-database applications, exit-with-failure may be ok. But if you have an app which requires cleanup, you will need to do a graceful exit. If you have, for example, a multi-threaded server, you will want to free memory associated with that thread, so you will need the old pointer value.